# Android Recognize user again after deleting an app

Tags: android

In my app I want to recognize the users again if they deleted the app and install it again.

I am looking for some detail I can use to do that. IP adress is bad idea because IP can change. User Registration is good idea, but I don't want the users to register.
Good idea is to use the IMEI, but I don't know if it is legal.

Which detail can I use to get what I want (legal way only)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Android ID which only changes with a factory reset:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score -1):

It's perfectly legal to use IMEI, just call [android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29)

This requires the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```